# using VB based DLL and/or ocx file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dllimport

I had recently bought a fingerprint cum card reader machine. And with it came the API so that i may use it through network from my pc. The problem is that i am building application based on C#.net and the api documentation says build on vb. Secondly i am not able to include and use it in my C# application.

Kindly try it and tell me how to use it on my c# application.The complete api rar file is linked below. Kindly download it nd help

link:   http://www.4shared.com/rar/TfD6vyOdce/SDK.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Option is:

```
Add the DLL via the solution explorer - right click on references --> 
add reference then "Browse" to you DLL - then it should be available.
```

Second, option is :
//Unmanaged C++ dll example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

//You may need to use DllImport

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Cadence\SPB_16.5\tools\bin\mpsc.dll")]
static extern void mpscExit();
```

//or

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
```

//Then each of those are called like this:

```
mpscExit();  // a specific DLL method/function call 
MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Test", "Test Dialog", 0);
```

## // user32.dll is Microsoft, path not nee

small exapmle in console application

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;     // DLL support

class HelloWorld
{
    [DllImport("TestLib.dll")]
    public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL ();

    static void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("This is C# program");
        DisplayHelloFromDLL ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, your code is in Vbasic. just open the rar file, you will find a dll nd ocx. How can i use them in my c# application to read inputs from the machine.

Comment: thanks for reply can i use the same code for ocx files also?

Comment: may be it's also usefull for *.ocx file